# LD_PRELOAD in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Is there any way to set LD_PRELOAD (or similar) in NetBeans 8?

I'm developing an application with java & PLCIO (via JNI)
It works fine when I launch it from a script in the following way:

> export LD_PRELOAD="/PathToMyLibs/libplc.so /PathToMyLibs/libplccip.so"
>
> java -Djava.library.path="/PathToMyLibs/" -classpath /PathToMyJars/ myApp.Main

I can even attach a debugger to  NetBeans. Cool.

But... I'd really need to run the application from inside the IDE to run my JUNit cases and have more control over the debugger

Any tip?

Comment: Take a look at the project"s ANT script...

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I don't understand it. Do you mean the build.xml? placing something like; <env key="${ld.preload.name}" file="${libjsig}"/> ?